# Can @Subcomponent be a subinterface of parent @Component?

Tags: dagger-2

Is there a way to make a `@Subcomponent` interface extend its parent `@Component` interface?  Does Dagger 2 intentionally disallow this?

I've successfully created a subcomponent that can inject anything its parent component can inject, provided I give it methods to do so:

```
@Singleton @Component(modules = ParentModule.class)
public interface ParentComponent {
    void inject(SomeObject object);
    ChildComponent plus(ChildModule module);
}

@ChildScope @Subcomponent(modules = ChildModule.class)
public interface ChildComponent {
    void inject(SomeObject object);
    void inject(SomeOtherObject object);
}
```

However, the subcomponent interface does not have an inheritance relationship with the parent component interface.  I tried making it extend the parent interface, but this does not compile:

```
@ChildScope @Subcomponent(modules = ChildModule.class)
public interface ChildComponent extends ParentComponent {
    //void inject(SomeObject object);
    void inject(SomeOtherObject object);
}
```

As far as I can tell, the error message does not explain why:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project dagger-test: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project dagger-test: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to extend the interface? Since it's a subcomponent, it has access to the whole parent graph, so just inject your elements in your subcomponent, those just depending on the parent in the parent, and you're done.

Comment: @bleeding182 All the activities and fragments in my app require the same handful of `@Singleton` dependencies, except for a couple fragments in one activity which require an additional activity-scoped dependency.  I thought it would be nice if that one activity could override the getter for the injector to return a more capable subclass.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have discovered a solution.  The `@Component` and `@Subcomponent` interfaces cannot have a direct inheritance relationship with each other, but they *can* both extend interfaces that do.  And the inject methods can be in those superinterfaces:

```
public interface ParentInjector {
    void inject(Injectable obj);
}

public interface ChildInjector extends ParentInjector {
    void inject(Injectable2 obj);
}

@Singleton @Component(modules = ParentModule.class)
public interface ParentComponent extends ParentInjector {
    ChildComponent childComponent();
}

@ChildScope @Subcomponent(modules = ChildModule.class)
public interface ChildComponent extends ChildInjector {}
```

`Injectable` and `Injectable2` have no inheritance relationship:

```
public class Injectable {
    @Inject @Named("foo") String mFoo;
}

public class Injectable2 {
    @Inject @Named("foo") String mFoo;
    @Inject @Named("bar") String mBar;
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why use subcomponent instead of component dependency? Component dependencies can inherit from each other (and they should).

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I tried that first and must have done something wrong because I didn't get it as close to working.  (I've only been using Dagger2 for a few days.)  But now I like this subcomponent solution better because my app can refer to the components by their superinterfaces and not see implementation details like the `ChildComponent` factory method.